# Does it make sense to cache image in memory in Android?

Tags: android, caching, android-recyclerview

`RecyclerView.Adapter` `onBindViewHolder` looks now like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserSettingHolder userSettingHolder, int i) {
   // .. some code
    try {

        // TODO: Image loader need
        File file = new File(MainActivity.context.getFilesDir(), _id + ".photo");
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        int numRead = in.read(buf);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buf, 0, numRead);
        userSettingHolder.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

I guess it is not efficient to read file always from filesystem especiall not in `onBindViewHolder` which is called quite frequently. Would you suggest to use a 'memory cache' for storing images? In iOS `NSCache` is offered for this. The `NSCache` has an an advantage if you are running out of memory it will be purged first.

What is the alternative technology in Android?

Comment: LruCache /////....

Comment: also few hints ... do not use decodeByteArray in onBindViewHolder nor io operation ... use another thread for this ... but ...it is hard to implement good because of view recycling (loading image1 to view1 is started... view 1 is recycled.. loading of image2 to view1 is started ... loading image2 is finished ... loading of image1 is finished ... wrong image is showed)... so use one of the already existing image loaders library ... which mostly has memory caching

Comment: Picasso, Glide, Universal Image Loader.Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

There are have lot of third-party library which can be used in this situation.
Here is an example with glide :

```
     Glide.with(context)
    .load(filePath)
    .setMemoryCache(new LruResourceCache(yourSizeInBytes))
    .into(youImageView);
```

Lib : https://github.com/bumptech/glide